# How to chang all <input> to its value by clicking a button and change it back later?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The problem: I have a page with many `<input>` fields (just say all are text fields)
I would like to have a button, when click on it, all input fields will become plaintext only.
e.g. `<input type="text" value="123" />` becomes 123
and if I click on another button, the text will change back to 
e.g. 123 becomes `<input type="text" value="123" />`

Is there an automatic way to scan for all the `<input>`s and change them all at once using javascript and jquery.

Thank you!

---

Edited
Seems you guys are getting the wrong idea.
Read what I have written again: e.g. `<input type="text" value="123" />` becomes 123

I have value="123" already, why would I want to set the value again???

What I want is e.g.

`<body><input type="text" value="123" /><input type="text" value="456" /></body>` becomes `<body>123456</body>` and later `<body>123456</body>` back to `<body><input type="text" value="123" /><input type="text" value="456" /></body>`

Comment: No. I dont want to set the value of the `<input>`. I want the `<input>` becomes its value!

Comment: You need to store information about `input` elements somehow, since from the data 123456 alone you cannot know whether it should become 123 and 456 or e.g. 12345 and 6 – and of course you would not know which characters to turn to `input` elements and what attributes to put into them. The information can be stored in markup or in variables. The formulation of the question seems to exclude markup, so you need to effectively create a copy of the document structure. I wonder what the original problem is. It probably has a simpler solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this to go one way,

```
$('input').replaceWith(function(){
    return $('<div />').text(this.value).addClass('plain-text');
});​​​
```

and this to go the other.

```
$('.plain-text').replaceWith(function(){
    return $('<input />').val($(this).text());
});
```

​

Comment: Thank you! With a little tweak, this concept of adding new class using replaceWith save my day.

Answer (score 2):

Check this link http://jsfiddle.net/Evmkf/2/

### HTML:

```
<div id='divInput'>
    <input type="text" value='123' />
    <br/>
    <input type="text" value='456' />
    <br/>
    <input type="text" value='789' />
</div>
<div id='plainText' style='display:none'></div>
<div>
    <input type="button" id='btnPlain' value='Make It Plain' />
    <input type="button" id='btnInput' value='Make It Text' />
</div>​
```

### Javascript:

```
$("#btnPlain").bind('click',function(){
  $("#plainText").html('');
  $("#divInput input[type=text]").each(function(index){
    $("#plainText").append('<span>'+$(this).val()+'</span>');
    $("#divInput").hide();
    $("#plainText").show();
  });
});

$("#btnInput").bind('click',function(){
  $("#divInput").html('');
  $("#plainText span").each(function(index){
    $("#divInput").append('<input type="text" value="'+$(this).text()+'"/><br/>');
    $("#plainText").hide();
    $("#divInput").show();
  });
});
```

​

Comment: You should always copy the code into your answer because jsfiddle might not be around forever.

Comment: Thank you so much, this definitely works, but I dont want to maintain a separate `<div>` for the `<input>`s.

Answer (score 1):

Try [this FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/keWpt/)

```
$(function() {
    var arr = [];
    $('#btn').on('click', function() {
        var $text = $('#inp input[type="text"]');
        if( $text.length > 0){
            $text.each(function(i) {
                arr[i] = this.value;
            });
            $('#inp').html(arr.join());
        }
        else{
            if(arr.length <= 0){
            }
            else{ // Add Inputs here
                var html = '';
                $.each(arr, function(i){
                    html += '<input type="text" value="' + arr[i]+ '"/>'
                });
                 $('#inp').html(html); 
            }
        }
    });
});
```

​

Comment: Thank you very much! But this is beyond my understanding...sorry, someone else may make good use on your code.

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a hidden element for each input, then use jquery to hide the input, show the hidden element and give it the inputs value.

```
<input type="text" value="123" id="input_1" />
<div id="div_1" style="display:none;"></div>

$("#div_1").html($("input_1").val());
$("#input_1").hide();
$("#div_1").show();
```